# preg for validating URL

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a 'bulletproof' preg expression for validating url. 
The regex should be true for following addresses

```
ftp://usernam@someurl.com
http://hh-1hallo.msn.blabla.com:80800/test/test/test.aspx?dd=dd&id=dki
http://twitter.com/test
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
telnet://example.org:8888
http://www.google.com/search?q=good+url+regex&rls=com.microsoft:*&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1
ftp://joe:password@ftp.filetransferprotocal.com
https://some-url.com?query=&name=joe?filter=*.*#some_anchor
```

But should return false to following:

```
http    .org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
http://hh-1hallo. msn.blablabla.com:80800/test/test.aspx?dd=dd&id=dki 
google.com
example.org
```

Comment: Just added a regex validating what you want

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with web site like [RegExLib.com](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url) ("url" section) ?

You should find what you need and test it for yourself there.

Anyway, this regex validate what you wants and exclude what you do not want.

```
(?ms)^(https?|ftp|telnet):\/\/((?:(?:(?=[^\r\n]*@)\w|-)+(?:(?::)(?:\w|-)+)?)?)@?((?:(?:(?:\w|-)+)\.)+(?:\w|-)+)(\:\d+)?((?:(?:/(?:\w|-)+(?:\.(?:\w|-)+)?)+)?)((?:\?(?:(?:\w|-)+\=(?:\w|[\.\-\*\:\+\#])*\&?)+)*)$
```

with:

- group 1: protocol
- group 2: username[:password]
- group 3: domain (www.xxx)
- group 4: empty
- group 5: address (XX/yyy/zzzz)
- group 6: parameters (?key1a=value1a&key2a=value2a?key1b=value1b&key2b=value2b...)

Comment: nothing wrong with that but I found this: ((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?) which doesn't return true for ftp://test@example.com

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
\^(https?|ftp|telnet):\/\/((?:[a-z0-9@:.-]|%[0-9A-F]{2}){3,})(?::(\d+))?((?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)*)(?:\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?$/i
```

This was based on code found here: http://snipplr.com/view/6889/regular-expressions-for-uri-validationparsing/ with several edits.

You can test it on this page:
http://regexpal.com/
(paste the regex as:

```
^(https?|ftp|telnet):\/\/((?:[a-z0-9@:.-]|%[0-9A-F]{2}){3,})(?::(\d+))?((?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)*)(?:\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?
```

and select "case insensitive")

Good luck!

Comment: @depesz yeah I know but I don't need it to validate

Comment: Hmm, so you need to not only validate whether the URL is valid, but whether the host is a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN)?  Would it be possible to use the provided regex in combination with a name lookup to validate the host?  Or would it be enough to just require a dot somewhere in the host?